# Extract values from array w Jolt

Tags: json, jolt

JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "cabinetId": 3,
    "anotherId": 1,
    "positionIds": [
      1019149753,
      987654321
    ]
  },
  {
    "cabinetId": 10,
    "anotherId": 2,
    "positionIds": [
      97812316
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to unnest values from arrays, so I expected:

```json
[
  {
    "cabinetId": 3,
    "anotherId": 1,
    "id": 1019149753
  },
  {
    "cabinetId": 3,
    "anotherId": 1,
    "id": 987654321
  },
  {
    "cabinetId": 10,
    "anotherId": 2,
    "id": 97812316
  }
]
```

Tried with:

```json
[
 {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "positionIds": {
          "*": {
            "@": "[&1].id",
            "@(2,cabinetId)": "[&1].cabinetId"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But now I have only arrays.

P.S. Sorry that I keep removing my config from `code` section. Editor throws an error and asks me to add more details.

Doesn't work with:

```json
[
  {
    "cabinetId": 12,
    "anotherId": 11,
    "positionIds": [
      1019149753,
      987654321
    ]
  },
  {
    "cabinetId": 10,
    "anotherId": 10,
    "positionIds": [
      97812316
    ]
  },
  {
    "cabinetId": 10,
    "anotherId": 10,
    "positionIds": [
      123456789
    ]
  }
]
```

I receive:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1019149753,
    "cabinetId": 12
  },
  {
    "id": 987654321,
    "cabinetId": 12
  },
  {
    "id": [
      97812316,
      123456789
    ],
    "cabinetId": [
      10,
      10
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: It's invalid field, I don't need this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can walk through the indexes of **positionIds** such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "positionIds": {
          "*": {
            "@": "[&1].id",
            "@(2,cabinetId)": "[&1].cabinetId",
            "@(2,anotherId)": "[&1].anotherId"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // accumulate each array within a single object 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // dissipate the values by indexes of the components within the arrays
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&].&1"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: Thanks! What if another field will be added to source json? I updated question.

Comment: you're welocme @takotsubo I've added the case.

Comment: Thanks again! I tried with another file, and it doesn't work properly. I don't know why. Seems like structure same, but... I attached not working example.

Comment: When cabinet_id is repeated (not unique), then this config works on a wrong way.

Comment: well, I've just edited @takotsubo